# Why is my constructor working incorrectly?

Tags: php

Here is the example of code:

```
class Empolyee{
    static public $nextID = 1;
    public $ID;
    public function __construct(){
        $this->ID = self::$nextID++;
    }
    public function NextID(){
        return self::$nextID;
    }
}

$bob = new Employee;
$jan = new Employee;
$simon = new Employee;

print $bob->ID . "\n";
print $jan->ID . "\n";
print $simon->ID . "\n";
print Employee::$nextID . "\n";
print Eployee::NextID() . "\n";
```

The above code returns `1,2,3,4,4` but for this I'm misunderstanding that it should return `2,3,4,5,5` because within the class Employee the value of `$nextID` is **1** then when creating a new object the contructor function is automatically initiated as if the value is **increased by 1**. So when creating first object, the `$bob`, here it should return 1+1= **2**. Please make my concept clear about this. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ref: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.increment.php

```
Example     Name            Effect
++$a        Pre-increment   Increments $a by one, then returns $a.
$a++        Post-increment  Returns $a, then increments $a by one.
```

So in your case, it always return the current $nextID before adding it by 1.

Comment: +1, your answer is correct, but please, please for the love of the web and all that is good in the world, I implore you from the bottom of my developer soul, don't refer **anyone** to w3schools. See http://www.w3fools.com/.

Comment: agreed with @Alex. Update the reference to the official documentation

Answer (score 0):

```
$this->ID = self::$nextID++; is POST INCREMENT
```

Set the $ID of $bob to 1 and then increments $nextID to 2 (the increment is AFTER (POST) the assignment completes - ie.  it's the same as:

```
$this->ID = self::$nextID;
self::$nextID = self::$nextID + 1
```

This cycle them repeats for @jan and then $simon

If you want ID to increase before the assignment use PRE INCREMENT

```
$this->ID = ++self::$nextID;
```